# iOS 10 webview doesn't open the app scheme

Tags: ios10

Is it iOS 10 bugs or change something in iOS 10 ?

Current code

```
window.location.replace("myappURL://app");
```

is working on iOS 9 in webview.

However, it cannot open anymore in iOS 10.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

LSApplicationQueriesSchemes is required in iOS10 for all app schemes that you want to open from webviews. 
This was not required in iOS9 or earlier but is in iOS10.
Add it like this in your Info.plist:

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>myappURL</string>
</array>
```